# ECONNRESET error while launching an application on openfin browser through angularcli

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, angular-cli

[image]

I am using combination of protractor,cucumber,typescript with angularcli for automation of a webapplication which works in openfin browser and i found attached error While launching the application.

Comment: Try running `ng build --aot` and ensure that you have no errors.

Comment: I ran ng build --aot command, it executed without errors and still the issue remains same